# Does send() and recv() implement reliable data transfer(TCP protocol)?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I want to know that if the socket is in a connected state with SOCK_STREAM transfer, does the packet sent between send() and recv() did reliable TCP protocol? Something like ACK and seq number for prevent the packet lost and correctness, or I need to implement the TCP protocol by myself?

Also,

If UDP without connect() with SOCK_DGRAM, does the packet sent between sendto() and recvfrom() did the UDP protocol? (ACK, seq number or timer...)

Comment: You can treat a `SOCK_STREAM` as a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do not** need to implement TCP or UDP yourself.

From `man 2 socket`:

> SOCK_STREAM
>   Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based byte streams.
>
> SOCK_DGRAM
>         Supports datagrams (connectionless, unreliable messages of a fixed maximum length).

From `man 7 tcp`:

> tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          This  is  an implementation of the TCP protocol defined in RFC 793, RFC 1122 and RFC 2001 with the NewReno
>          and SACK extensions.

From `man 7 udp`:

> udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   This  is an implementation of the User Datagram Protocol described in RFC 768.

Also see `man 7 socket`, `man 2 send`, and `man 2 recv`.

All referenced man pages are from the "Linux Programmer's Manual".